# matrix_basis doesn't set to the values I am setting it to

Tags: armature, import, keyframes, matrix, quaternion

So, I'm importing animation data from a text file, containing the bonematrix for each frame and each bone. I am simply setting the matrix_basis of each bone and adding a keyframe, and repeating. The issue is the matrix is not being set correctly. Here is my code:

```py
    animInfo = readFile("animationInformation.txt")

    sce = bpy.context.scene

    ob1 = bpy.data.objects['obj_armature'] #object with animation

    for f in range(0, animInfo['NumFrame']):
        sce.frame_set(f)
    
        lazy_counter = 0
        for bone in ob1.pose.bones:

            dictMatrix = animInfo['Frames'][f]['BoneMatrix'][lazy_counter]
            matrix = mathutils.Matrix((dictMatrix[0], dictMatrix[1], dictMatrix[2], dictMatrix[3]))

            deltaX = animInfo['Frames'][f]['FramePlusX']
            Y = animInfo['Frames'][f]['FramePosY']

            console_print(matrix)
            bone.matrix_basis = matrix
            console_print(bone.matrix_basis)

            if (lazy_counter == 0):
                bone.location = mathutils.Vector((bone.location[0] - deltaX, Y, bone.location[2]))
                bone.keyframe_insert("location", frame=f)

            bone.keyframe_insert("rotation_quaternion", frame=f)
        
            console_print(lazy_counter, bone)
            #bone.rotation_mode = "XYZ"
            lazy_counter = lazy_counter + 1
```

and my output is:

```
<Matrix 4x4 ( 1.0000, 0.0500, -0.0200, 0.0000)
            (-0.0600, 1.0000, -0.0800, 0.0000)
            ( 0.0100, 0.0800,  1.0000, 0.0000)
            ( 0.0000, 0.0000,  0.0000, 1.0000)>
<Matrix 4x4 ( 0.9984, 0.0542, -0.0171, 0.0000)
            (-0.0554, 0.9953, -0.0793, 0.0000)
            ( 0.0128, 0.0801,  0.9967, 0.0000)
            ( 0.0000, 0.0000,  0.0000, 1.0000)>
35 <bpy_struct, PoseBone("bone_35") at 0x000001C922193408>
```

I even avoided setting matrix_basis directly and converted my input matrix to euler angles and used those to set the rotation, and it ended up basically having the same exact issue of being slightly wrong.

None of my bones have constraints or anything, so I'm confused.

Apologies, I am new to blender and importing things.

Answer (score 3):

**Blender Matrices require the axes to be orthogonal.**

The axes can be gleaned from the matrix's 3x3 rotation part. Normalizing removes scale component.

```
 x, y, z = M.to_3x3().normalized().col
```

Blender transform matrices are required to have their axes [orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix), taking your example matrix

```
>>> M = Matrix((( 1.0000, 0.0500, -0.0200, 0.0000),
...             (-0.0600, 1.0000, -0.0800, 0.0000),
...             ( 0.0100, 0.0800,  1.0000, 0.0000),
...             ( 0.0000, 0.0000,  0.0000, 1.0000)
...             ))
>>> M.is_orthogonal_axis_vectors
False
```

Nope, not ortho,

```
>>> pb
bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones["Bone.001"]
```

but if assigned to a blender object where this is a requirement

```
>>> pb.matrix_basis = M
```

The matrix is adjusted such that they are.

```
>>> print(pb.matrix_basis)
<Matrix 4x4 ( 1.0002, 0.0545, -0.0172, 0.0000)
            (-0.0555, 0.9997, -0.0795, 0.0000)
            ( 0.0128, 0.0805,  1.0001, 0.0000)
            ( 0.0000, 0.0000,  0.0000, 1.0000)>

>>> pb.matrix_basis.is_orthogonal_axis_vectors
True
```

**Closest Orthogonal Matrix**

Blender is using some routine to convert a matrix to its [Nearest Orthogonal Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix#Nearest_orthogonal_matrix)

$$Q = M \left(M^\mathrm{T} M\right)^{-\frac 1 2}$$

Using the `numpy` method from [dokato/orthogonalization.py](https://gist.github.com/dokato/7a997b2a94a0ec6384a5fd0e91e45f8bhttps://gist.github.com/dokato/7a997b2a94a0ec6384a5fd0e91e45f8b)

```
import numpy as np
from mathutils import Matrix

# https://gist.github.com/dokato/7a997b2a94a0ec6384a5fd0e91e45f8bhttps://gist.github.com/dokato/7a997b2a94a0ec6384a5fd0e91e45f8b

def closest_orthogonal_matrix(A):

    MAX_ITER  = 2000

    TOLERANCE = np.max((1, np.max(A.shape) * np.linalg.svd(A.T, False, False)[0])) * np.finfo(A.dtype).eps# TODO
    reldiff     = lambda a,b: 2*abs(a-b) / (abs(a)+abs(b))
    convergence = lambda rho, prev_rho: reldiff(rho, prev_rho) <= TOLERANCE

    A_b  = A.conj()
    d = np.sqrt(np.sum(A*A_b,axis=1))

    rhos = np.zeros(MAX_ITER)

    for i in range(MAX_ITER):
        scA = A.T * d
        u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(scA, False)
        V = np.dot(u, vh)
        # TODO check is rank is full
        d = np.sum(A_b*V.T, axis=1)

        L = (V * d).T
        E = A-L
        rhos[i] = np.sqrt(np.sum(E*E.conj()))
        if i > 0 and convergence(rhos[i], rhos[i - 1]):
            break
    return L
```

Running on `M`

```
Q = closest_orthogonal_matrix(np.array(M.transposed()))
print(Q)
```

outputs

```
[[ 1.00020448 -0.05563547  0.01295613  0.        ]
 [ 0.05456417  0.99970566  0.08056127  0.        ]
 [-0.01738446 -0.07964211  1.00007397  0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          1.        ]]
```

which is pretty much blender result above.  Blender uses row ordered matrices, to get result above have transposed the blender matrix.

**Important Note:** In hindsight Would be more correct to do this  only with the 3x3 matrix part, as the translation (4th column) should not be treated as an axis vector.

and FWIW, the difference of the two matrices and the determinant of the difference.

```
>>> M - pb.matrix_basis
Matrix(((-0.00022614002227783203, -0.004478182643651962, -0.002794567495584488, 0.0),
        (-0.0044654011726379395, 0.00027042627334594727, -0.0004532337188720703, 0.0),
        (-0.0027905991300940514, -0.00045549124479293823, -8.809566497802734e-05, 0.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)))

>>> (M - pb.matrix_basis).determinant()
0.0
```